# AWS S3 files CORS issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I want to use my assets in my s3 bucket in a kaboomJs code on loading a sprite:

`loadSprite("bg", "https://cubie.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bird.png");`

but I'm getting this error:

*Access to image at 'https://cubie.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/bird.png' from origin 'https://example.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

this is my S3 bucket CORS configuration:

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Could you try to add `"HEAD"` in `AllowedMethods` too?

Comment: @juanfontes I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: I've run a demo using kaboomjs with a bucket that I have with the same configuration that yours have and it worked well. I've used a bike: https://imgur.com/a/THLRJ0T

- Are you running your app by `npm`? Because if you are just opening the file in your browser, chrome isn't able to handle CORS things. 
- Is your bucket publicly accessible too?

Comment: thanks, @juanfontes. I found the problem, it was related to my s3 settings and policy. I posted the solution.

Comment: glad you solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, it was about my S3 settings and policy.
I changed the **Resource** from `arn:aws:s3:::example` to `arn:aws:s3:::example/*`